# values show up correctly in view, but not template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following view, which shows up correctly in the print report details:

```
def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername='request.user.formattedusername')
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values('report_name')

    print(reportdetail)
    args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportdetail}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

However, it's not getting passed to my template correctly.  I'm new to Django so I'm going to assume there is something wrong the part of my template passing the report name.

```
      <h2>Current Access Application List</h2>
      <ul>
{{reportdetail.report_name}}
        <li>Application Name: {% for app in reportdetail %}
             <input type="checkbox" name="report_name" value="{{ app.report_name }}" /> {{ reportdetail.report_name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        </li>

      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you have,

```
args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportdetail}
```

which does not match your loop in the template

```
{{ reportdetail.report_name }}
{% for app in reportdetail %}
```

You should either change the view to:

```
args = {'user':owner, 'reportdetail':reportdetail}
```

or change the template to use `applicationaccess`.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response Alasdair, for my understanding what is the difference in the first part and second part of the 'name':name.

Comment: `{'name':name}` is a confusing example because you are repeating `name`. Consider `{'name': 'Nick'}` instead. The key is `'name'`, so when you use `{{ name }}` in the template, you get the value `'Nick'`.

Comment: How would I remove the query set text part from the value, when calling the key in the template?  Current Access Application List
Application Name: <QuerySet [{'report_name': 'ALL_REPORTS'}]>

Comment: That question doesn't really make sense. Since it's a queryset you can either loop through it, e.g. `{% for app in reportdetail %}{{ app }}{% endfor %}`, or access an item by index, e.g. `{{ reportdetail.0 }}`.

Comment: That part works great, but in my application it shows up as <QuerySet [{'report_name': 'ALL_REPORTS'}]> instead of just ALL_REPORTS.  Perhaps I asked the question incorrectly, i'm sorry.

Comment: I don't understand. What code causes `<QuerySet [{'report_name': 'ALL_REPORTS'}]> ` to show up, and where does it show up?

Comment: That is the value of reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values('report_name') when I review the print.  It displays on my template just as the output in the python console from print.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to print `reportdetail` or include `{{ reportdetail }}` in your template. It's a queryset, so as I said you should loop through it. Perhaps you expect the queryset to contain a single item. In that case you should be using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) (which returns an object) instead of [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter), which returns a queryset.

Comment: Ok, i understand now.  Thank you for your kind help.  So typically in a query set you wouldn't include it in your template.  I want it to return multiple values, but in my instance I have access to all reports other users won't so i want to see each report, which is why i used a forloop.

Comment: When I try reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.get(ntname = owner.formattedusername) it states object is not iterable, but i need it to be since in most cases there will be more than one value.  Is there something other than filter or get?

Comment: If you expect the query to multiple items sometimes, then you should use `filter()`, and loop through the queryset. This will work even when the queryset only has a single item.

Comment: Then i'm still having the problem where template displays <QuerySet [{report_name': 'Value(s)' ]>  I only want to see the 'Values', not the <QuerySet[{report_name': text included as well.

Comment: You haven't said what the template code is that is causing `<QuerySet [{report_name': 'Value(s)' ]>` to display. You shouldn't get that if you do `{% for app in reportdetail %}{{ app }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: {% for app in applicationaccess %}
              {{ applicationaccess }}<br />
        {% endfor %}   with my args as args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportdetail} ahh it's because I was using applicationaccess instead of app.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's right, it should be `{{ app }}` inside the for loop.